# MySQL aggregation

Tags: mysql, aggregation

Hi all I am trying to aggregate the number of searches that clients are doing. I currently have this working for 1 day. I would also like to put in a column for searches for that week, month, year and total

```
    USE live_travelcoglog; 
    SELECT lu.Name, lu.UID, IFNULL(l.AgentId, 'CP Total') AS "CP", COUNT(*) AS   "DateTotal", MAX(l.Submitted) AS "LastSearchTime" 
    FROM logs l INNER JOIN live_travelcog.users lu ON l.ChannelPartnerId = lu.CustId 
    WHERE Submitted BETWEEN '2014-04-23 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-23 23:59:59' 
    AND l.MessageType = 'COG_HotelAvail_RS' 
    GROUP BY lu.Name, l.AgentId ASC WITH ROLLUP;
```

[image: Search Results]

Now I can run the queries for the different values that I am after but I am sure there is a nicer way that they can all be grouped together. If someone could kindly point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Daz

Comment: what is the question? there is no question.

Comment: @mpm - "I would also like to put in a column for searches for that week, month, year and total", it's not a question, but it's pretty obvious what he's asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you were looking for?

```
USE live_travelcoglog; 
SELECT
    lu.Name,
    lu.UID,
    IFNULL(l.AgentId, 'CP Total') AS "CP",
    SUM(Submitted BETWEEN '2014-04-23 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-23 23:59:59') AS DateTotal,
    SUM(Submitted BETWEEN '2014-04-17 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-23 23:59:59') AS WeekTotal,
    SUM(Submitted BETWEEN '2014-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-23 23:59:59') AS MonthTotal,
    MAX(l.Submitted) AS "LastSearchTime" 
FROM logs l
INNER JOIN live_travelcog.users lu
    ON l.ChannelPartnerId = lu.CustId 
WHERE
    l.MessageType = 'COG_HotelAvail_RS'
GROUP BY
    lu.Name,
    l.AgentId ASC
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: Thanks, Its so clear when someone does it like that. Never though of moving the date to the select.